# Does the polynomial $P(x)$ have integer zeros?

Tags: polynomials

The following is a homework question:

> Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients and $P(x_1)=P(x_2)=P(x_3)=P(x_4)=P(x_5)=P(x_6)=P(x_7)=7$ where $x_i$ are distinct integers. Determine if $P(x)$ has integer zeros.

I've never done questions like this before. I started with this:

If $\deg(P) = 7$,

$$P(x)=\alpha(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)(x-x_5)(x-x_6)(x-x_7)+7$$

where $\alpha$ is some integer.

However, the question doesn't state that the polynomial must be of the seventh degree. Even then, I don't see how I can determine if $P(x)$ has integer  zeros without knowing all the $x_i$.

Can someone please help me? Thanks.

**Edit:**
Is this a valid solution?
$$P(x)=Q(x)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)(x-x_5)(x-x_6)(x-x_7)+7$$

If $P(n)=0$,
$$Q(n)(n-x_1)(n-x_2)(n-x_3)(n-x_4)(n-x_5)(n-x_6)(n-x_7)=-7$$

where $Q(x)$ is a polynomial of integer coefficients (therefore $Q(n)$ is an integer)

And since all the terms on the LHS are integers and the $x_i$ are distinct integers, it follows that some of the factors on the LHS $\ne$ {$\pm 1, \pm 7$}. And $7$ is a prime number, therefore $n$ cannot be a zero.

Comment: I think you need to add that $P$ is monic, i.e. that the lead coefficient is $1$. Otherwise if $Q(x)=(x-x_1)\dots(x-x_7)+7=R(x)+7$, the poly $((nx-1)R(x)+1)Q(x)$ has $\frac1n$ as a root, and evaluates as $7$ at the $x_i$.

Comment: @TomOldfield Why is $1/n$ a root? If I read correctly, it gives $Q(1/n)\neq 0$.

Comment: Does $P(x) = 7$ count as a polynomial?

Comment: $7$ is a prime number.

Comment: @user17762 Well even if it does, it wouldn't make a difference, right? $P(x)=7$ doesn't have any integer zeros.

Comment: @Angie $P(x) = 7$ has no zeros (let alone integer zero). Hence, $P(x)$ need not have integer zeros.

Comment: @TomOldfield Maybe. I'm not sure. I wrote it in the exact way the problem was stated.

Comment: @user17762 I think the question is asking if there is any $P(x)$ that **does have** integer zeros.

Comment: What you should prove is that if $x$ is a root of $P$, then it can't be an integer. So take such an $x$. Evaluate. And consider achille hui's comment again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$P(x)= Q(x) (x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)(x-x_5)(x-x_6)(x-x_7)+7$

Idea : You can't get $-7$ by multiplying $7$ distinct integers..

Comment: We'll save the argument for the day when $7$ will be replaced by some badly composed integer, +1.

Comment: I think what I included after editing my original post is similar. @julien Can you please check if it's correct? Thanks.

Comment: Right ,exactly..

Comment: @Angie Nicely done. Just add $-7$ to the list of values $\{\pm 1,\pm 7\}$.

Comment: @Angie, you need to mention $Q(x)$ is a polynomial of integer coefficients.

Comment: Thank you guys. I've included both your corrections in the edit.

Comment: I think you're using the "Rational Root theorem". The term $Q(x)(x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_7)$ has a constant term which adds to 7, so the possible roots may be other than 1, -1, 7 and -7...

Comment: I fixed  it ,,thank you , we don't need that at all..

Comment: Where did the "-7" come from?